# Creating RSS2.0, RSS1.0 compatible feed parser

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, rss, rss-reader

I have to create an RSS reader on the Salesforce platform. I read the specification of RSS 1.0 and 2.0.

In RSS 2.0, the format specified in this document http://feed2.w3.org/docs/rss2.html, there is nothing like an extension in it, without modules and namespace like we see in RSS 1.0, in which we define XML even after the closing of the `channel` item. For example, in this link http://static.userland.com/gems/backend/rssTwoExample2.xml there is only one RSS parent element above `channel`, but when we take the case of RSS 1.0, it contains a lot of siblings like in this example.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<rdf:RDF 
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"
>

  <channel rdf:about="http://www.xml.com/xml/news.rss">
    <title>XML.com</title>
    <link>http://xml.com/pub</link>
    <description>
      XML.com features a rich mix of information and services 
      for the XML community.
    </description>

    <image rdf:resource="http://xml.com/universal/images/xml_tiny.gif" />

    <items>
      <rdf:Seq>
        <rdf:li resource="http://xml.com/pub/2000/08/09/xslt/xslt.html" />
        <rdf:li resource="http://xml.com/pub/2000/08/09/rdfdb/index.html" />
      </rdf:Seq>
    </items>

  </channel>

  <image rdf:about="http://xml.com/universal/images/xml_tiny.gif">
    <title>XML.com</title>
    <link>http://www.xml.com</link>
    <url>http://xml.com/universal/images/xml_tiny.gif</url>
  </image>

  <item rdf:about="http://xml.com/pub/2000/08/09/xslt/xslt.html">
    <title>Processing Inclusions with XSLT</title>
    <link>http://xml.com/pub/2000/08/09/xslt/xslt.html</link>
    <description>
     Processing document inclusions with general XML tools can be 
     problematic. This article proposes a way of preserving inclusion 
     information through SAX-based processing.
    </description>
  </item>

  <item rdf:about="http://xml.com/pub/2000/08/09/rdfdb/index.html">
    <title>Putting RDF to Work</title>
    <link>http://xml.com/pub/2000/08/09/rdfdb/index.html</link>
    <description>
     Tool and API support for the Resource Description Framework 
     is slowly coming of age. Edd Dumbill takes a look at RDFDB, 
     one of the most exciting new RDF toolkits.
    </description>
  </item>

</rdf:RDF>
```

For creating a standard parser which deals with the core part, it's easy to get the description and link of each item. But when we talk about RSS 1.0 in any element, when we see any `rdf:resource` attribute in the element, then we have to find the `rdf:about` attribute in a sibling of the `channel` element and find its description and link in it.

Please provide a guideline about how to parse RSS 1.0 to get the description and link of each item in feeds. Or is my assumption correct?